# Truecrypt as server (?) on two crossover-cable connected Windows machines

Tags: networking, truecrypt

Here's a small problem I got. Hope someone can help me out.

1. Two machines connected by a crossover-cable. One got XP, the other Win7
2. Exchange works fine: read and write from and to both machines
3. Mount two truecrypt volumes (not file containers): one on each machine
4. Writing files from the tc-volume one machine to the tc-volume on the other does not function

Question: how come? And how to solve?

Comment: As always: Read the documentation! http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sharing-over-network

Comment: @mailq That doesn't address this poster's problem.

Comment: Reading the manual indeed does not answer my question. First: that part in the manual is actually quite short. Second: it suggests that the construction I am trying to create should work, which it does not. I already checked the forum and other internet sites.

Comment: I'll bet the SMB file-sharing protocol is not insulated enough from the overlaying filesystem for this to work.  TrueCrypt has a driver encrypting the data written by the filesystem to the volume (which is the SMB client-side in this case), but I'll bet those encrypted blocks are confusing SMB, which probably expects to look inside at the filesystem data for some reason.